# Java - how to use the vertex buffers object in LWJGL?

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, slick2d

I am trying to use the vertex buffers object.

At first there wasn't any problem until I got into this nasty situation:

```
glPointSize(2.0f);
glBegin(GL_POINTS);
for (Entity p : points) {
    glVertex3f(p.x, p.y, p.z);
}
glEnd();
```

How can I convert this into the Vertex Buffers Object render?

I mean as you can see, the data (x, y, z) are changed every time for each point (it's a loop ).

So how can i implement the Vertex Buffers Object render into this?

Answer (score 8):

Basically what you want it putting all the vertex data into a `FloatBuffer`, and then pass it to OpenGL. I've created a little example of a VBO storing Vertices and Colors for a Triangle and rendering it and also how to delete it!

#### Creating the VBO

This is the code where you create the actual Vertex and Color Buffer and bind them to the VBO.

```
int vertices = 3;

int vertex_size = 3; // X, Y, Z,
int color_size = 3; // R, G, B,

FloatBuffer vertex_data = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(vertices * vertex_size);
vertex_data.put(new float[] { -1f, -1f, 0f, });
vertex_data.put(new float[] { 1f, -1f, 0f, });
vertex_data.put(new float[] { 1f, 1f, 0f, });
vertex_data.flip();

FloatBuffer color_data = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(vertices * color_size);
color_data.put(new float[] { 1f, 0f, 0f, });
color_data.put(new float[] { 0f, 1f, 0f, });
color_data.put(new float[] { 0f, 0f, 1f, });
color_data.flip();

int vbo_vertex_handle = glGenBuffers();
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo_vertex_handle);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertex_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

int vbo_color_handle = glGenBuffers();
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo_color_handle);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, color_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

You can of course add more Vertices and Colors to the `vertex_data` and `color_data` if you want to! But always remember that the amount of vertex data, need to match with the amount of color data and vice versa!

**Important:** Only create the VBO(s) once, and only update them when necessary! Don't create them for each frame, since them you will end up with a frame-rate worse than when using immediate mode for rendering!

#### Rendering the VBO

This is the code you need to call, to render the VBO.

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo_vertex_handle);
glVertexPointer(vertex_size, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0l);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo_color_handle);
glColorPointer(color_size, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0l);

glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertices);

glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
```

#### Deleting the VBO

Then when you're done with the VBO and you don't need it anymore, you can delete it by doing the following.

```
glDeleteBuffers(vbo_vertex_handle);
glDeleteBuffers(vbo_color_handle);
```

Comment: Since you're not using interleaved VBOs, why not use an array of `GLubyte` to store the color? It is definitely more difficult to do mixed-type interleaved VBOs in Java because of the stupid `FloatBuffer`, `ByteBuffer`, etc. semantics, but ubyte colors are always the preferred way to store colors unless you are doing something HDR.

Comment: I agree using OpenGL with Java can be tricky and dumb in a lot of ways. Though as far as I know you can't use `GLubyte` with `LWJGL` in `Java`.

Answer (score 1):

Here are good tutorials on buffers:

- [Following the Data](http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/Basics/Tut01%20Following%20the%20Data.html)
- https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Buffer_Object

Regarding your question:

I suggest creating a VBO for maximum number of points (or maybe num of points is constant). Then fill this buffer with NULL.

When you want to render points you need to `map` buffer and update its content.

```
float *data = (float *)glMapBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, GL_WRITE_ONLY);
update_points(data); // write new positions for all points
glUnmapBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER);
```

Then you draw it via:

```
bind_and_set_your_buffer();
glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, VertexCount);
```

- for updating you can consider using: glBufferSubData, or glMapBufferRange

Comment: did you see it was a Java OpenGL related question and not C++ ?

Answer (score 1):

I had same trouble and Vallentin's answer is very satisfying. So, for sake of JOGL, I want to share whole code with public.

```
package alican_tuts.VBO;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;

import javax.media.opengl.GL2;
import javax.media.opengl.GLAutoDrawable;
import javax.media.opengl.GLEventListener;
import javax.media.opengl.awt.GLCanvas;
import javax.media.opengl.glu.GLU;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import com.jogamp.common.nio.Buffers;
import com.jogamp.opengl.util.FPSAnimator;

public class VBO_Example extends GLCanvas implements GLEventListener {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private static String TITLE = "AliCan VBO EXAMPLE";
    private static final int CANVAS_WIDTH = 800;
    private static final int CANVAS_HEIGHT = 600;
    private static final int FPS = 60;

    private GLU glu;

    // VBO related variables
    int vertices = 3; // Triangle vertices

    int vertex_size = 3; // X,Y,Z
    int color_size = 3; // R, G, B

    private FloatBuffer vertex_data;
    private FloatBuffer color_data;

    private int[] vbo_vertex_handle = new int[1];
    private int[] vbo_color_handle = new int[1];

    // ===========================================================
    // GUI creation and program's main function
    // ===========================================================
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                GLCanvas canvas = new VBO_Example();
                canvas.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT));

                final FPSAnimator animator = new FPSAnimator(canvas, FPS, true);

                final JFrame frame = new JFrame();

                frame.getContentPane().add(canvas);
                frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {

                        new Thread() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                if (animator.isStarted())
                                    animator.stop();
                                System.exit(0);
                            }
                        }.start();
                    }
                });
                frame.setTitle(TITLE);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
                animator.start();
            }
        });
    }

    public VBO_Example() {
        this.addGLEventListener(this);
    }

    // ===========================================================
    // VBO Related Functions
    // ===========================================================

    private void initVBOs(GL2 gl) {
        vertex_data = Buffers.newDirectFloatBuffer(vertices * vertex_size);
        // vertex_data = FloatBuffer.allocate(vertices * vertex_size);
        vertex_data.put(new float[] { 0.0f, 1.0f, 0f });
        vertex_data.put(new float[] { -1.0f, -1.0f, 0f });
        vertex_data.put(new float[] { 1.0f, -1.0f, 0f });
        vertex_data.flip();

        color_data = Buffers.newDirectFloatBuffer(vertices * color_size);
        // color_data = FloatBuffer.allocate(vertices * color_size);
        color_data.put(new float[] { 1f, 0f, 0f });
        color_data.put(new float[] { 0f, 1f, 0f });
        color_data.put(new float[] { 0f, 0f, 1f });
        color_data.flip();

        gl.glGenBuffers(1, vbo_vertex_handle, 0);
        gl.glBindBuffer(GL2.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo_vertex_handle[0]);

        gl.glBufferData(GL2.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices * vertex_size * Buffers.SIZEOF_FLOAT, vertex_data,
                GL2.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        gl.glBindBuffer(GL2.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

        gl.glGenBuffers(1, vbo_color_handle, 0);
        gl.glBindBuffer(GL2.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo_color_handle[0]);
        gl.glBufferData(GL2.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices * vertex_size * Buffers.SIZEOF_FLOAT, color_data,
                GL2.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        gl.glBindBuffer(GL2.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    }

    private void renderVBOs(GL2 gl) {
        gl.glBindBuffer(GL2.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo_vertex_handle[0]);
        gl.glVertexPointer(vertex_size, GL2.GL_FLOAT, 0, 0l);

        gl.glBindBuffer(GL2.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo_color_handle[0]);
        gl.glColorPointer(color_size, GL2.GL_FLOAT, 0, 0l);

        gl.glEnableClientState(GL2.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL2.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

        gl.glDrawArrays(GL2.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertices);

        gl.glDisableClientState(GL2.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
        gl.glDisableClientState(GL2.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    }

    // ===========================================================
    // OpenGL Callback Functions
    // ===========================================================
    @Override
    public void init(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
        GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();
        glu = new GLU();
        gl.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        gl.glClearDepth(1.0f);
        gl.glEnable(GL2.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        gl.glDepthFunc(GL2.GL_LEQUAL);
        gl.glHint(GL2.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL2.GL_NICEST);

        gl.glShadeModel(GL2.GL_SMOOTH);

        initVBOs(gl);
    }

    @Override
    public void reshape(GLAutoDrawable drawable, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();

        if (height == 0)
            height = 1;
        float aspect = (float) width / height;

        gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

        gl.glMatrixMode(GL2.GL_PROJECTION);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        glu.gluPerspective(45.0, aspect, 0.1, 100.0);

        gl.glMatrixMode(GL2.GL_MODELVIEW);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
    }

    @Override
    public void display(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
        GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();
        gl.glClear(GL2.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL2.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        gl.glLoadIdentity();

        gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, -6.0f);
        renderVBOs(gl);
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
    }

}
```

Comment: Your code isn't fully correct as you don't create direct NIO buffers, you should call com.jogamp.common.nio.Buffers.newDirectFloatBuffer(int) instead of FloatBuffer.allocate(int). Please replace 4 by Buffers.SIZEOF_FLOAT, it is much more readable. You can use com.jogamp.opengl.util.ImmModeSink as a temporary solution. Your code doesn't work with JOGL 2.3.0 RC because of this change: https://jogamp.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=682

Comment: @gouessej Thank you very much for your warnings and advices. But, I really did not know that what makes it different by  allocating buffers from com.jogamp.common.nio packet. Can you please give me a biref explanation?

Comment: Better than words: https://github.com/sgothel/gluegen/blob/master/src/java/com/jogamp/common/nio/Buffers.java#L79 https://github.com/sgothel/gluegen/blob/master/src/java/com/jogamp/common/nio/Buffers.java#L121 To sum up, you create some indirect NIO buffers and it forces JOGL to create direct NIO buffers under the hood (to communicate with the native OpenGL / OpenGL ES calls) whereas it is easier, safer and more straightforward to create the direct NIO buffers by yourself. Moreover, com.jogamp.common.nio.Buffers chooses the native byte order, lots of developers forget to do it.

Comment: N.B: "javax.media" has been moved to "com.jogamp" in JOGL 2.3.1. By the way, "System.exit(0)" should be necessary only in an application launched by Java Webstart, it's not mandatory here. When the last visible window is closed, the JVM shuts down.