# Rendering large VBO objects in jogl

Tags: java, opengl, rendering, jogl, vbo

I am trying to render large VBO array objects, containing ~700000 values and I have ~1500000 values in my element_array buffer. But what I am getting is a blank screen. On the other hand if I just use only the VAO, my code works correctly. My code is as follows:

```
    //Data buffers
    FloatBuffer vertexBuffer = GLBuffers.newDirectFloatBuffer(this.coordCount);
    vertexBuffer.put(Vertices);
    vertexBuffer.rewind();

    IntBuffer indexBuffer = GLBuffers.newDirectIntBuffer(this.indexCount);
    indexBuffer.put(index);
    indexBuffer.rewind();

    //setting up the VBO
    int nVBO = 2;
    int[] VBO = new int[nVBO];

    gl.glGenBuffers(nVBO, VBO,0);

    gl.glBindBuffer(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO[0]);
    gl.glBindBuffer(GL.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,VBO[1]);

    gl.glBufferData(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this.coordCount*Float.SIZE, vertexBuffer, GL.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    gl.glBufferData(GL.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, this.indexCount*Integer.SIZE, indexBuffer, GL.GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    gl.glBindBuffer(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO[0]);
    gl.glBindBuffer(GL.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO[1]);

    gl.glEnableClientState(GLPointerFunc.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

    gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL.GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);
    //gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer);


    //gl.glDrawArrays(GL.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
    gl.glDrawElements(GL.GL_TRIANGLES, this.indexCount, GL.GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
    //gl.glDrawElements(GL.GL_TRIANGLES, this.indexCount, GL.GL_UNSIGNED_INT, indexBuffer);


    gl.glDisableClientState(GLPointerFunc.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glBindBuffer(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    gl.glBindBuffer(GL.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

Any clues/suggestions on how I can fix this?

Comment: Does it work for *small* VBO objects?

Comment: Yes, I have tried it out for 50 triangles, and it is working for that. But not for large dataset.

Comment: What GPU are you using? Are you running software emulation?

Comment: Have you ensured that the application does not simply hang at loading the data?

Comment: This is the graphics card model : 01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Whistler [Radeon HD 6730M/6770M/7690M XT] (rev ff)

Comment: The application doesn't hang, it gets really slow, and everything starts to lag.

Answer (score 0):

Is this code block called each time when the loop runs? If it is, you should divide your vbo phases into different blocks.[This sample code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28434322/1156111) may help you how to divide. (In the link that I post, you should just focus initVBO and renderVbo functions) I guess your initializing your vbo's sequentially, which it may make your program unresponsive.